# How append version hash to style files via webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-file-loader

How i can append version hash to files (images/fonts) via webpack? In example i have style in source:

**header.scss**

```
.image__logo {
    background-image: url(/assets/images/logo.png);
}
```

After compile i need a version hash as a postfix of filename (or will be better to see timestamp of last modified of this file):

**header.css**

```
.image__logo {
    background-image: url(/assets/images/logo.png?3f5e48a065eb836da00d);
}
```

I tried to add loader, but it not work:

```
    {
      test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
      loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]?[hash]!extract-loader!html-loader'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the question mark in your file name pattern, which is breaking the query string. Try specifying the name explicitly via `options`, *e.g.:*

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
                name: "[name].[ext]?[hash]"
            }
        },
        {
            loader: "extract-loader"
        },
        {
            loader: "html-loader"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Simply posting some code isn't terribly helpful. Can you explain your code? That way others can understand and learn from your answer instead of just copying & pasting some code from the web.